# (Java) Add two longs which sum is higher than long max range

Tags: java, methods, compare

I need to create a function that search into a file with 20 million of longs if there are two elements which sum is equal to a random **long** number passed as parameter. These 20 millions of Longs are loaded into an ArrayList. My problem is: if I convert these two elements into two long variables, I add them and then I store the result into a generic long variable called "sum", it doesn't works because the sum is higher than the maximum range of the long type. How can I solve this? I saw that exist a class called BigInteger, but as written as this it doesn't works and I think it's a bit confused as solution:

```
long n1=Long.valueOf(array.get(0));
long n2=Long.valueOf(array.get(1));
BigInteger sum = new BigInteger(Long.toString(n1)).add(new BigInteger((Long.toString(n2))));
BigInteger element = new BigInteger(Long.toString(elem));
if (sum.compareTo(element)==0) return true;
```

Comment: you can use `BigInteger.valueOf(n1)` instead of converting the long to a string.

Comment: How do you know it does not work?

Comment: Unclear what needs to be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, this is how arithmetic with big numbers works in Java. Arithmetic operators in Java only work on primitive number types, so to do it on objects representing numbers, it needs to be done using methods.

Some JVM languages do take advantage of operator overloads (Kotlin, Groovy, Scala), but this is a feature that is not planned for the Java language.

Comment: The OP is using `BigInteger.add` method. I did not see any relation between the question and the answer.

Comment: As opposed to BigInteger + BigInteger?